# Tabbing mysteriously disabled in Flash application

Tags: flash, focus, accessibility, swfobject, tabbing

I'm compiling a SWF using FlexSDK 4.1.  I am not disabling any tab functionality.  Swf is being embedded with the following via swf object:

swfobject.embedSWF("Main.swf", "flashcontent", "984", "550", "10.0.0",  params,flashvars, attributes, "expressInstall.swf");

Expected outcome when tabbing is to see "yellow boxes" on all items with click events.  I don't see anything all browsers.  WMODE is 'window'

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is in your swf? buttons? input fields? is it flex or pure as3?

Comment: Hey kodiak, It's pure AS3.  The buttons are Custom classes that extend Sprite, contains a MovieClip exported from a SWC and a custom Class that extends TextField using an embedded CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MS Windows, you can obtain the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279) and pull Inspect32 to see what the OS is providing you when you can't see the focus. It could be off screen or a non-visual focus.

Comment: -1 The OS focus is on the Flash Player, the OP is asking about the focus inside the Flash Player.

Comment: +1 to cancel out ;) - inspect32 is still a useful tool here; Flash player implements the IAccessible interface that exposes its internal focus to tools such as inspect; so inspect can track both HWND focus, and focus *within* certain other types of HWNDs. For inspect to see anything here, though, you may need to mark the base flash objects as being accessible, since AFAIK basic sprites are not accessible/tabbable by default, though stock controls like buttons do have this support.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a FLASH object embedded in a web page? If so - the problem is that various browsers differ on whether they let you tab into a FLASH object (or any plugin, not just FLASH) in the first place.

- Try it with IE - IE lets you tab in, through, and back out of FLASH objects.
- Chrome and Firefox - these tab right over the object. The only way you can tab through FLASH objects in these is to click the object to force focus there - which somewhat defeats the purpose of using the keyboard in the first place... (It might be possible to use element.focus() to get focus there - but then the typical problem is that focus is stuck within the FLASH object and never returns back to the page...)

As a reference, try playing with a youtube page. They've done the work to make their FLASH plugin accessible, but it only works in some browsers, as outlined above.

Note that if/when you do get focus to the object, the focus highlight is drawn by flash itself; so you won't see the browser's focus style (eg. dotted line for IE, yellow rectangle for chrome), but you should see *something*.

On top of all of this, if you're extending from one of the very base classes (rather than deriving from an existing higher-level control such as a button), you might need to set some properties on your class to make the item keyboard-tabable, and also visible to accessibility clients (such as screen readers). You might need to also provide your own visuals to indicate when the element has focus yourself.